# Add unnumbered blank page after cover page, but before title page and book

Tags: titles, double-sided, books, blank-page, single-sided

Right after the cover page **[TEMP IMAGE A]**, I'd like to get a **blank page** (which would be unnumbered and unaccounted for in the overall page count), then the book's title page **[TEMP IMAGE B]** (which should be numbered "i"), followed immediately by the **TOC** (ii), the **LOT** (iii), and so forth.

Keep in the mind that I've made this book one-sided. I've played around with localizing a double-sided argument to get that blank page after the cover page but failed.

Thank you for your help.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage{epigraph}
%\usepackage{caption} % To change the way captions are labelled
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

\usepackage[
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=teal,
urlcolor=teal
]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\newlength{\drop}

\begin{document}

    \onecolumn
    \includepdf{example-image-a}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \drop=0.1\textheight
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\[8ex]
            \LARGE{TITLE PAGE OF THE BOOK}
    \end{titlepage}
    \twocolumn

    \cleardoublepage

    \frontmatter
    {
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=teal}\textbf{}
        \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % Removes dots for Sections and under
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \clearpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage

\onecolumn
\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Preface}
\Blindtext
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\twocolumn

\clearpage

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Table.}
        \label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            A & B \\
            \hline
            1 & 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have some issues in your code, for example do you load `fonspec` but use also `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`. Why do you use `\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}` and not package `geometry`? Do you really need all that called packages? Do only use those of them you exactly know what they are doing ...

For your issue simply add the following code snippet:

```
\clearpage
~
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
```

`\clearpage` starts a new page and `\thispagestyle{empty}` makes sure that there are no header and footer printed.

To get rid of the blank page after the title page comment out the two commands `\twocolumn` and `\clearpage`  after `\end{titlepage}` ....

Please see the following shortend LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading (space between lines)

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

\usepackage[
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=teal,
urlcolor=teal
]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\newlength{\drop}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn
\includepdf{example-image-a}
\clearpage % <==========================================================
~
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage % <==========================================================
    \begin{titlepage}
        \drop=0.1\textheight
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\[8ex]
            \LARGE{TITLE PAGE OF THE BOOK}
    \end{titlepage}
    %\twocolumn % <===============================================

    %\cleardoublepage % <=========================================

    \frontmatter
    {
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=teal}\textbf{}
        \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % Removes dots for Sections and under
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \clearpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage

\onecolumn
\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Preface}
\Blindtext
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\twocolumn

\clearpage

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Table.}
        \label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
            \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
            A & B \\
            \hline
            1 & 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

and see its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

and page 3 and 4:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works ... partially. It does add a blank page after the TEMP IMAGE A, but there's still a blank page numbered "i" right before the TOC. I'd like the TOC to start right after the TITLE PAGE ... and that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: As for the code, yes, you are correct, there are weird things with it. But (1) I can't fix them, (2) you only have a portion of the entire code, and (3) the book actually compiles perfectly, as expected, albeit with some minor log errors here and there.

Comment: @CyanideBaby to get rid of the blank page after title page just comment out commands `\twocolumn` and `\cleardoublepage` after the title page ... see updated answer